# Const char conversion error

Tags: c++, cstring

I am getting the following error with gcc.

```
invalid conversion from ‘char**’ to ‘const char**’
```

With this code.

```
void foo( const int &argc, const char **argv );

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   foo( argc, argv );                                                            
}
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 8):

When used in function parameter list, `char *argv[]` declaration is equivalent to `char **argv` declaration. For this reason, when you are passing `argv` to `foo` you are actually attempting to convert  `argv` from `char **` type to `const char **` type. This is illegal. Read the FAQ http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17 for why it is illegal.